# Build steps: "invoke ant" vs. "running ant from shell"

Tags: jenkins

I am currently using jenkins to deploy an application under intended release conditions, and I'm being forced to run JUnit tests on the deployed system as root user (since the application has certain files that are only accessible by the root only).

Instead of using the "invoke ant" build step to run the tests, I am running ant using sudo from the "execute shell" build step, something like...

```
sudo ant -file build.xml -D.... test
```

since the jenkins user has the neccesary root permissions to do this but not acccess the files mentioned above.

I realize that doing this creates some folders in the workspace with the wrong permissions, but I correct this after from "execute shell".

Everything seems to wok alright but it feels like a bit of a workaround.

My question then, is there any disadvantage of running ant in this manner compared to the build step "invoke ant"?...or can anyone see a better way of doing this?

Comment: I should have added that I have no concerns about windows. It is purely for testing on Linux (Rhel 6) Thanks for all the input. Feels a bit safer having a few experts give some input. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins translates "invoke ant" with a shell command, you can check this watching the console output of a build, so if you've solved your problem the way you say I think that it's the same

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. yes, that's the way I came upon the above solution by watching the output from a similar job. But, I just felt there might be some repercussions down the line.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind ANT build step is that it provides uniformity across platforms. So you should use it as much as possible in order to avoid "configuration hell" - combinatorial explosion in the number of different configurations. Sometimes, however, a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do.

Answer (score 1):

Given your constraints, I think your solution is just fine.

To answer your question:

```
...is there any disadvantage of running ant in this manner...?
```

The primary one that comes to mind is if you have a distributed Jenkins deployment, with some slaves running Windows, and some slaves running UNIX, then this clearly won't work (or at least would require more work - e.g., installing/configuring Cygwin). But I don't think that's something you are really concerned with.

An alternative solution that is arguably cleaner is to set up a single Jenkins slave that runs as root (and "Administrator" on Windows if that's needed) and tie your job to it, sticking to "invoke Ant" for you Ant invocations. But that requires significantly more work to set up, and probably isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Using ant from a shell doesn't seem problematic if everything works fine. As you've mentioned, modified file permissions might be an issue after execution.